# mAuth.getCurrentUser().isEmailVerified() always returns false the first time

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm detecting if the email is validated with firebase via the instruction shown on the title and it works, but with an strange error.

First time it tries to verify mail even if verified it says it's not verified. When method is again executed it returns it's verified.

I've checked that this is not a time issue, even if I leave a long time from the moment I verify the email to the moment I tell the app to check if it is verified, it always fails on its first attempt.

What could I do so, if the email is verified, it returns that it is verified from the first attempt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently you are still using the old Firebase IdToken and hence it shows the old state. The same issue occurs when you update user's custom claims but if you still keep using the old idtoken then the custom claims won't reflect.

```
user.getIdToken(true).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<GetTokenResult>() {
  @Override
  public void onSuccess(GetTokenResult result) {
    String idToken = result.getToken();
    //Do whatever
    Log.d(TAG, "GetTokenResult result = " + idToken);
  }
});
```

You should pass true in the getIdToken so it'll refresh the token and then check if the email is shown verified in the first go. To make sure whatever I have explained above, you can try logging the idtoken and see if the email was verified on old and new idtoken.